# Good place to ask health based questions?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry

I like the development of biology.stackexchange.com, but it is still in an early stage and far from perfection. While we develop it further, could you guys help me finding places to ask questions related to health and biochemistry in general?

Comment: Since this question is more about the Q&A site rather than an actual question on the topic, I think this belongs on meta.

Answer (score 2):

Health: [ask your doctor](https://biology.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Biochemistry: ask here, there are already [>100 biochemistry questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biochemistry).

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to ask health questions from a student - not pacient - viewpoint? That is, I want to find papers, data and literature about certain topics. Do you/someone here know?

Comment: In that case you're still the closest to on-topic here. I don't think we have any professionals for medicine here yet but as a fellow medical student I might be able to help. Plus there are people with extensive knowledge on human biology, which tends to cover a lot of health topics.